# MariaDB wrong dateformat

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mariadb

I have a query that do not format correctly a date and don't undertand why:

```
SET @start='2020-01-01 23:00:00';
SELECT MIN(@start) AS `start`, MIN(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(@start,'+0:00','+02:00'), '%d/%m/%Y')) AS `startp`;
SELECT MIN(`start`) AS `start`, MIN(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`start`,'+0:00','+02:00'), '%d/%m/%Y')) AS `startp` FROM sessions
```

The results of the query above is this:
First and correct output:
[image: FIRST QUERY]
Second and wrong output:
[image: SECOND QUERY]

Can anyone find what's wrong?

Comment: `SELECT MIN(\`start\`) FROM sessions ` gives `2020-01-01 23:00:00`? What type is `start` in?

Comment: @user3783243 `start` is datetime

Comment: Issue does not reproduce, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a40f96/1.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND THE ISSUE:
I use the MIN function after dateformat and this is wrong cause is not datetime format anymore.
So before I search the min and after format the result:

```
SELECT MIN(`start`) AS `start`, DATE_FORMAT(MIN(CONVERT_TZ(`start`,'+0:00','+02:00')),'%d/%m/%Y') AS `startp` FROM sessions
```